# Utilizing a while loop to create combo boxes within Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I need combo boxes to be placed in specific positions in relation to the cells on this Worksheet. I was attempting to utilize a while loop to change a variables value and utilize that variable to dynamic change a cell. However, my code doesn't seem to be working. The loop will run through once, but will give me a "object does not support this property or method" error on the successive loop.

```
Dim t As Integer

Dim wotype as object

t = 1

Do While t < 43

    wotype = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, Left:=Cells(4, t).Left, Top:=Cells(3, t).Top, Width:=25.29, Height:=Rows(3).RowHeight)

    t = t + 3

Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When assigning an object to a variable, you need to use the `Set` keyword...

```
set wotype = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, Left:=Cells(4, t).Left, Top:=Cells(3, t).Top, Width:=25.29, Height:=Rows(3).RowHeight)
```

Although, in this case, since you're not subsequently referring to your variable, your code can be re-written as follows...

```
Dim t As Integer

t = 1

Do While t < 43

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl xlDropDown, Left:=Cells(4, t).Left, Top:=Cells(3, t).Top, Width:=25.29, Height:=Rows(3).RowHeight

    t = t + 3

Loop
```

Comment: Thanks. This was super simple and I, ironically, used set to do the exact same thing in another macro on the same worksheet. I appreciate the time you took to fix my blatant error